# tail a file on network Windows IoT Core machine

Tags: windows

Is it possible to tail a file on a Windows network machine?

For a linux machine I can

`ssh  -t remotebox "tail -f /path/to/file.log"`

Note. The ssh is open on the destination machine.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell:

```
get-content C:\Users\Example\Example.txt -tail 10
```